Zsh: How to workaround "no matches found" issue
I want to check whether filename extensions of my images are correct, that is, whether my JPEGs are really JPEGs, PNGs are really PNGs, and WebPs are really WebPs. For this, I use the following command:
file *.{jp*,png,webp}

It works fine, but only if I have at least one .jp*, one .png, and one .webp file in a target folder. Otherwise, that is, for example, if there are only .jp* and .png files, there will be an error:
zsh: no matches found: *.webp

How to workaround this issue? That is, how to tell Zsh to search for all the three patterns, that is, *.jp*, *.png, *.webp, but if one or more of them are not found, then to not complain and simply process the remaining ones?

Does this answer your question? How to get rid of "No match found" when running "rm *"

@kos Thanks. Well, yes and no. The link includes solutions how to workaround this issue by using setopt, which chaghes the global Zsh behavior, if I understand correctly. But what if I don't want to change the global Zsh behavior, and all I want is to execute a one single command?

file -- *.(jp*|png|webp)

That is using a glob to match *. followed by any of jp* or png or webp.
In *.{jp*,png,webp}, the brace expansion happens before globbing. So it's equivalent to three separate globs *.jp*  *.png   *.webp - all of which are subject to the nomatch shell option.

Hello, rowboat, many thanks. I have just discovered that if using ImageMagick's magick identify instead of file, another solution is to use quotation marks. That is, you can use either magick identify *.(jp*|png|webp) or magick identify "*.{jp*,png,webp}". Do you know whether any difference between these two?

@jsx97 In the second one magick must be doing its own evaluation of that expression (although idk what that is, sorry).

I suppose the alternative with brace expansion would be *.{jp*,png,txt}(N), not that I'm sure that has any advantages compared to *.(jp*|png|webp), and might be worse in that if no file at all matches, the command would run without args.

@ilkkachu It seems you mean "not that I'm not sure that [it] has any advantages [...]"

A side note: It seems in Bash file *.{jp*,png,webp} works fine, whereas file "*.{jp*,png,webp}" doesn't work. Weird...

@jsx97, hmm, I don't think what I wrote was wrong? I'm not sure it has any advantages. It might not have any. Anyway, I'm not that an expert in English grammar, or even in stock phrases.

Quotes stop globbing as usual. They also stop brace expansion. That's sort of the point of quotes, to make special characters non-special (apart from $ and backslash in double quotes). Same happens in zsh.

@ilkkachu So did you mean that *.{jp*,png,txt}(N) is more dangerous than *.(jp*|png|webp)?

@jsx97, not really. I said it might not have any advantages over the other one. The possible issue there is that e.g. ls *.{jp*,png,txt}(N) expands to ls *.jp*(N) *.png(N) *.txt(N), where each separate glob is removed if it doesn't match anything. That's fine as long as at least one of them matches, but if that doesn't happen, they all get removed, so the commands that runs is ls without any args, and it lists the current directory contents. Which may not be desired. I'm not sure that's a danger as such, though, just a possible issue.

To correct myself: Above, I have wrote: "It seems you mean ..." I simply misread what ilkkachu wrote. He wrote "not that I'm sure", whereas I misread it as "note that I'm sure". Hence my confusion.
